# C# application connects to SQL Server remotely first two times but crashes the third

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-express

I have a SQL class that reads and writes data to a remote SQL Server database.  When I start up the application, it connects and reads 2 tables but as soon as it tries to read the 3rd table, the application throws an exception :

> A network-related instance or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.

My connection string looks as follows :

```
server=My-PC\SQLEXPRESS;database=DB_main; User Id=**;password=*****; Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

That connection string works fine while reading the first 2 tables but crashes when reading the third.

My SQL class contains a function that retrieves the connection string that was saved to a text file. And then for every table I have a function that connects to the database and reads all rows and returns it as a strongly typed `List<T>`

Example :

```
public List<User> ReadAll_Users()
{
    string Table_Name = "Table_Users";

    sqlCommand2 = new SqlCommand();
    List<User> ListUsers = new List<User>();
    try
    {
        string path = GetPathOfDataBAse2();
        sqlconnection2 = new SqlConnection(path);
        sqlCommand2.Connection = sqlconnection2;
        sqlCommand2.CommandText = "Select * from " + Table_Name;

        sqlconnection2.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand2.ExecuteReader();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            User model = new User();

            model.Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]).ToString();
            model.Surname = Convert.ToString(reader["Surname"]).ToString();
            model.Created_Date =    Convert.ToString(reader["Created_Date"]).ToString();
            model.Password = Convert.ToString(reader["Password"]).ToString();

            model.Admin = Convert.ToString(reader["Admin"]).ToString();

            ListUsers.Add(User);
        }
        sqlconnection2.Close();

        return (ListUsers);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ErrorReport msg = new ErrorReport("SQLconnector,  ReadAll_Users()", ex.ToString());
        msg.ShowDialog();
        sqlconnection2.Close();
        return (null);
    }
}
```

All the functions follow the same technique.

What could I look at to fix this problem?

Comment: What does this bit do? string path = GetPathOfDataBAse2();

Comment: **Gosh** - why on earth **reinvent the wheel** YET again?!?!?!? There's **tons** of really useful and versatile micro-ORM's like Dapper out there that **already do all of this** for you!

Comment: Thanks for the comments I will take it into Consideration for my future projects.  The GetPathOfDataBase2() returns the connection string that i use to connect to the server just like i showed on top of this Question

Comment: Yes, but especially given the existence of a function with a suffix `2`, is it possible that the methods that work are calling one variant of this function and getting one connection string and the method that's failing is calling a *different* method and getting a different connection string? Giving us *one* example piece of code and expecting us to diagnose the issue is bad - especially when we don't even know if that's the working one or the non-working one. Maybe look at [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to close your reader.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you should dispose all SQL-related objects in your code (now you probably have non-disposed SqlCommand and SqlDataReader after the method is called). You can call Dispose() explicitly on SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataReader objects (it's better to do it in finally block rather than write the code twice in try and in catch blocks).

But it's even better to use the "using" statement. It works the same way (as disposing object in finally block) but you need less typing. As an example, the code may look like this:

```
public List<User> ReadAll_Users_st()
    {
        string Table_Name = "Table_Users";
        string path = GetPathOfDataBAse2();
        List<User> ListUsers = new List<User>();

        using (SqlConnection sqlconnection2 = new SqlConnection(path))
        using (SqlCommand sqlCommand2 = sqlconnection2.CreateCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                sqlCommand2.CommandText = "Select * from " + Table_Name;
                sqlconnection2.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand2.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        User model = new User();

                        model.Name = Convert.ToString(reader["Name"]).ToString();
                        model.Surname = Convert.ToString(reader["Surname"]).ToString();
                        model.Created_Date = Convert.ToString(reader["Created_Date"]).ToString();
                        model.Password = Convert.ToString(reader["Password"]).ToString();

                        model.Admin = Convert.ToString(reader["Admin"]).ToString();

                        ListUsers.Add(model);
                    }
                }
                sqlconnection2.Close();
                return (ListUsers);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ErrorReport msg = new ErrorReport("SQLconnector,  ReadAll_Users()", ex.ToString());
                msg.ShowDialog();
                sqlconnection2.Close();
                return (null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments , I should have given more information than i did , I apologize. I found the error. When i started the project I used SQL compact  I overlooked some code on the change to SQL server.  the error was at the line

```
`sqlconnection2 = new SqlConnection(path);`
```

at some point and time I should have changed every

```
`sqlconnection2 = new SqlConnection("Data Source = " + path + ";");`
```

to

```
`sqlconnection2 = new SqlConnection(path);`
```